# Create data relation on multiple columns

Tags: c#, dataset, relationship

I'm trying to create relation on multple columns but I get error like:

> column' argument cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: column

This is how I do it:

```
        MySqlDataAdapter table1;
        MySqlDataAdapter table2;

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        table1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, this.connection);
        table2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, this.connection);

        table1.Fill(myDataSet, "mainList");
        table2.Fill(myDataSet, "subList");

        myDataSet.Relations.Add(relationName, 
        new DataColumn[] { myDataSet.Tables["mainList"].Columns[fieldName1_1], myDataSet.Tables["mainList"].Columns[fieldName1_2] },
        new DataColumn[] { myDataSet.Tables["subList"].Columns[fieldName2_1], myDataSet.Tables["mainList"].Columns[fieldName2_2] }).Nested=true;

        return myDataSet;
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the names of the tables in your Relations.Add

Comment: Adding DataColumn requires two parameters : 1) a string name 2) A type like typeof(int)